# Implementing an iterator in Julia for an animation with PyPlot

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, julia

I am just trying to reproduce this simple [example](http://scipyscriptrepo.com/wp/?p=9)  of an animation in Matplotlib but using PyPlot in Julia. I am having difficulties with the definition of the iterator `simData()` that is passed to the function `funcAnimation` , because it seems that PyPlot doesn't recognize the iterator that I defined in Julia (via a [Task](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/control-flow/#man-tasks)) as such.

Here is my approach to define the same function `simData()`:

```
function simData()

    t_max = 10.0
    dt = 0.05
    x = 0.0
    t = 0.0

    function it()
        while t < t_max
            x = sin(pi*t)
            t = t+dt
            produce(x,t)
        end
    end
    Task(it)
end
```

As you can check, this kind of iterator yields in theory the same values than the python `simData()` generator of the example (try for example `collect(simData())`.  However, I got this error when I try to do the animation

```
LoadError: PyError (:PyObject_Call) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>
TypeError('PyCall.jlwrap object is not an iterator',)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1067, in __init__
    TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 913, in __init__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 591, in __init__
    self._init_draw()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1092, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))

while loading In[5], in expression starting on line 42

 in pyerr_check at /home/diegotap/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/exception.jl:56
 [inlined code] from /home/diegotap/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/exception.jl:81
 in pycall at /home/diegotap/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:402
 in call at /home/diegotap/.julia/v0.4/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:429
```

As I mentioned, I think the problem is that the Julia iterator is not recognized as such by Python. Do you have any idea about how to fix that?

PS: [Here](https://github.com/dapias/SimpleAnimation/blob/master/animacioniterador.ipynb) is a Jupyter notebook with the full code that I used to do the animation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your code, you invoke `FuncAnimation()` this way:

```
ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData, blit = false, interval=10, repeat= true)
```

In the original code, `simData()` was a generator, but in your code it isn't, it *returns* a generator, so I'd expect your code to invoke it this way:

```
ani = anim.FuncAnimation(fig, simPoints, simData(), blit = false, interval=10, repeat= true)
```

Let's finish the problem -- since we can't get Python to recognize the return value of `simData()` as an iterator, we'll ignore that feature and have `simPoints()` call `simData()` to launch the task and then return a function for Python to animate:

```
using PyCall
using PyPlot
pygui(true)

@pyimport matplotlib.animation as animation

function simData()
    t_max = 10.0
    dt = 0.05
    x = 0.0
    t = -dt

    function it()
        while t < t_max
            x = sin(pi * t)
            t = t + dt
            produce(x, t)
        end
    end

    Task(it)
end

function simPoints()
    task = simData()

    function points(frame_number)
        x, t = consume(task)
        line[:set_data](t, x)
        return(line, "")
    end

    points
end

figure = plt[:figure]()
axis = figure[:add_subplot](111)
line = axis[:plot]([], [], "bo", ms = 10)[1]
axis[:set_ylim](-1, 1)
axis[:set_xlim](0, 10)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(figure, simPoints(), blit=false, interval=10, frames=200, repeat=false)

plt[:show]()
```

This works for one pass of the bouncing ball across the graph and stops when it hits the right edge (unlike the original Python which repeats).